# I want to define a function for giving Identity of a chatbot; but chatbot can't understand my code

Tags: python, nltk, cosine-similarity, tfidfvectorizer

I want my chatbot introduce itself; but it does not understand my queries.

```
    GREETING_INPUTS = ("hello", "hi", "greetings", "sup", "what's up","hey",)
    GREETING_RESPONSES = ["hi", "hey", "*nods*", "hi there", "hello", "I am glad! You are talking to me"]
     def greeting(sentence):
        for word in sentence.split():
            if word.lower() in GREETING_INPUTS:
                return random.choice(GREETING_RESPONSES)
        Identy_Input = ("Who are you?","What is your name?","What's your name")
        Identy_Response = ["I am Robo, your virtual chatbot","THis is Robo, your virtual assistant"]

     def identity(sentences):
        for word in sentences.split():
            if word.lower() in Identy_Input:
                return random.choice(Identy_Response)
```

The conversation is like this:

```
ROBO: My name is Robo. I will answer your queries about Chatbots. If you want to exit, type Bye!
who are you
ROBO: I am sorry! I don't understand you
who are you?
ROBO: I am sorry! I don't understand you
Hi
ROBO: hi there
What's your name?
ROBO: I am sorry! I don't understand you
```

Comment: Here is the output:
ROBO: My name is Robo. I will answer your queries about Chatbots. If you want to exit, type Bye!
who are you
ROBO: I am sorry! I don't understand you
who are you?
ROBO: I am sorry! I don't understand you
Hi
ROBO: hi there
What's your name?
ROBO: I am sorry! I don't understand you

Comment: You're checking if each lowercase word entered is equal to a sentence with mixed capitalisation. That won't match! Try putting a few `print` statements in your `for` loops to see what is really being compared

Comment: Is this the full code? How each function should be called?

Comment: @EsdrasXavier I haven't write down the full code here.